# How to access other tenants and subscriptions in Azure?

Tags: java, azure

we are trying to write some application to retrieve metrics from Azure Monitor Service for collecting data and shipping them to Prometheus.

One tenant with many subsriptions is ok. We are using an app registration and a corresponding enterprise application (aka service principal).

With the identifiers of the app registration (usbscription_id, tenant_id, client_id and client_secret) a java app is registering in Azure and collecting this data.

But let's imagine that we could access our customers tenants and subscription in this way.
How could this be done in detail ?

Regards
Holger

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same approach as you are doing for your own tenant. Your customer's tenant should have an AAD application registration (service principal) having required **least privilege** in the target subscription (for example, monitoring reader in this case). Then use the tenant id, subscription id, client id, client secret/certificate from your java app to collect data.

It's strongly recommended as best practice that access control should follow principle of least privilege (give permissions to **only what is needed**) in the customer's subscription to avoid any inadvertent/accidental change.

Comment: Hi @krishg,

that is a legal proposal, but no best practice I think. We only want to use "our" subscription once and not the access data of the customer. There must be another way to proceed. Maybe some export of the service principal or something.

Comment: Yes, to access resource of a subscription, you would obviously need an identity of the corresponding tenant. There is also concept of [multi-tenant app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant), but that is useful for user interactive sign-in. But here you are more into background daemon app using client credential flow.